# Embdding of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: galois-theory

How to show that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ can not be embedded into a cyclic extension whose degree over $Q$ is divisible by $4$ ?

Is it true ? Although I'm stuck but I've really no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we can embedd it into a cyclic extension $K/Q$. Since $Gal(K/Q)$ is cyclic so exist an element of order $2$ which is no thing but the transposition in Galois group corresponding to complex conjugation of $i$. Now clearly $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(i))$ is cyclic of degree divisible by $2$ \implies that transposition is in $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(i))$ which is a contradiction since that transposition doesn't fix $\mathbb{Q}(i)$